# How can I determine local minima from a Kernel Density Estimation?

Tags: clustering, kernel-smoothing

I have a fairly large 1-dimensional array that I am trying to cluster. I came across several other questions on this site where the top answer is to use a Kernel Density Estimation and then locate local minima: [Determine different clusters of 1d data from database](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/40454/determine-different-clusters-of-1d-data-from-database/40475#40475) and [Alternative to Otsu for dividing data into two groups](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34452/alternative-to-otsu-for-dividing-data-into-two-groups/34454#34454).

I have successfully used [SciPy's gaussian_kde function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html) to generate KDE's for my data, and they plot beautifully, but how do I calculate the local minima?

Answer (score 1):

Compare each value to the two neighboring values.

If it is smaller than both of them, it is a local minimum.